# How to remove green check marks from OneDrive Windows 7

Tags: onedrive

Can someone please tell me if I'm able to remove the green check marks in OneDrive for Windows 7?  It just looks annoying to see all the green check marks.  Thanks, David

Comment: I found a good solution for Windows 7. If you can test and update or mark as answer if you agree it works.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 7, you want to remove the green checkmarks for folders inside OneDrive. In the Registry, it is called a ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers.

[image: Green Checkmark]

- Exit out of OneDrive so the cloud icon disappears from your system tray.

The easiest way to do this is to use [SysInternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

- Look for the entries that say SkyDrive1, SkyDrive2, and SkyDrive3 in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
- Uncheck all three boxes.
- If you are asked to Run As Administrator (UAC), agree and continue

[image: ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers for OneDrive disabled]

- Start OneDrive again
- Your folders will no longer show the green checkmark

[image: No Green Checkmarks]