# How to remove OneDrive icon overlay checkmarks in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I was wondering if there is an updated process known for removing the green check marks that overlay the OneDrive file icons? I searched high and low for a Windows 10 fix for this, but none are available.

This Windows 7 process does not work for Windows 10:
[How to remove green check marks from OneDrive Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/816372/how-to-remove-green-check-marks-from-onedrive-windows-7/816376#816376)

I tried the same steps and even went as far as trying to remove the similar reg entries in Windows 10, but they repopulate when explorer.exe is restarted.

This is a screenshot of my Autoruns OneDrive entries.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Download NirSoft ShellExView from [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)

You're searching for the entries highlighted in this screenshot:

[image]

Then restart Windows Explorer with Task Manager. Overlay icons should not appear from now on.

Disabling this overlay also fixes Documents folder being duplicated in Windows Explorer navigation sidebar.

Comment: Thank you VERY much this did the trick! No more green check marks covering file icons. I only dropped the 'UpToDateOverlayHandler Class' to keep the error, sharing, and syncing overlays when they occur (not as annoying). Thanks again!~gC

Comment: Very helpful, upvoted. Thank you. Onedrive icons competing with TortoiseGit was a real problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using regedit, navigate to:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers

You should see a set of folders like "OneDrive1", "Onedrive2", etc. Each of these relates to one of the overlay icons. You can delete them or rename them like "OneDrive1-D" to disable them. For reference if you only want particular icons disabled (for example only the obnoxious green overlay), their functions are:

1. Not syncing (red x)
2. Synced - Shared
3. Syncing - Shared
4. Synced
5. Syncing

References:

> [Which OneDrive icon/status is for which Icon Overlay Identifier name?](https://superuser.com/questions/1037648/which-onedrive-icon-status-is-for-which-icon-overlay-identifier-name)
>
> [Remove Green Check Mark Icon Overlay: Dropbox, SkyDrive, & Others](https://sumtips.com/tips-n-tricks/remove-green-check-mark-icon-overlay/)

Comment: Tried renaming #4, but OneDrive just reinstalled it. Tried editing the GUID inside to all zeroes, same result.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative tool for deactivating overlay icons is [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from Sysinternals:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The icon is in this DLL
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\17.3.6998.0830\amd64\FileSyncShell64.dll

I used IcoFX to open the DLL and edit the icon using the Opacity to turn them to -90%. I changed all 8 versions of the icon to make sure I got them all.

Once you save the icon file go to Tools, Icon Resource Editor and you can save your file back over the icon in the DLL.
I had to turn off OneDrive, renamed the .dll, then copied in my new FileSyncShell64.dll
Restart my computer, the icon is gone.

Answer (score -1):

**I strongly recommend you use Nirsoft ShellExView.**

But if for some reason you don't feel like or can't download it (maybe your internet connection was lost right after you loaded this thread)

GO TO REGISTRY EDITOR, THEN: 
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers

**The green checkmark is under OneDrive4** and deleting it should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

The green check marks are OneDrive's way to tell users that the file/icon is synced up with their personal OneDrive. The simplest way to turn off the checkmarks is to **go to OneDrive in the Hidden Icons tab in your taskbar, open Help & Settings, then click "Close OneDrive."** The green check marks should disappear.

Keep in mind that closing OneDrive will stop any newly created files from syncing with the OneDrive's cloud service, so if you ever want to sync up files with OneDrive, open the app until everything's synced then simply turn it back off.