# How to remove OneDrive sync status icons on Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync, onedrive, desktop-icons

I'm on Windows 10 and I have a question regarding OneDrive sync status icons. Usually, these are displayed in the File Explorer next to the file. I have Desktop sync set up in OneDrive so all my files from Desktop are synced there. What I would like to do is to get rid of the sync status icon for the icons on the Desktop. I don't mind about having the icons in Desktop when opened in File Explorer, but I would like to not have them on the actual icons on the actual Desktop. Is this somehow possible? I can see that for example shortcuts on the Desktop are already missing this icon, because it's overridden by the arrow icon showing that it's the shortcut.

Thank you

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/969655/how-to-remove-onedrive-icon-overlay-checkmarks-in-windows-10